# How long the URL of a YouTube video last before expiring?

Tags: video, youtube, date-time, youtube-dl

On executing `youtube-dl -g <youtube_link>` we get the urls for the video and the audio, we can play those urls with *vlc* for example.

But for how long those urls are valid?, they're of the form:

```
https://rr4---sn-uqx2-w50l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1703633398&ei=lg2LZYr4Jv_6j-8P45iR-Ak...
```

What's the meaning of that `expire=1703633398`.

Comment: The Youtube URL is quite different from what you've got there and doesn't change. Where are you getting these URLs from? Can you get the actual Youtube URL?

Comment: I have no source, but when there is an `expire` query in theyoutube's  url, it is usually set for 6 houra. In your example, the expiration date is Tuesday, December 26, 2023 11:29:58 PM GMT. The expiration time/date you privded `1703633398` is epoch/unix time. It is the number of seconds that has passed since 01 January 1970. You can go to https://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert it to human readable form.

Comment: That's a video codec stream from YouTube's CDN, they combine it with the audio stream to get a video. Also `youtube-dl` is dead software, I suggest moving to the much more powerful and actively developed [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/). I don't know what the expire query is but it's most likely for caching, so that after expiry ends the stream is re-fetched from the CDN. If so the URL itself shouldn't expire at all, and if using a tool like `yt-dlp` or `yt-dl` you usually don't need to worry about the codec streams anyway as they're built to handle them for you.

Comment: A `share` link on a youtube video is shorter and has no VISIBLE expiry, may be a better choice?

Comment: @music2myear Example `youtube-dl -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xi8Z-BdLuLo` the result is like `https://rr3---sn-uqx2-w50l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1703642294...`

Comment: So yt-dl parses the url to get that. It seems Google serves the actual video using this generated dynamic URL, and I would also guess you cannot use that url very freely, and it makes sense for it to be time-limited.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the meaning of that `expire=1703633398`

`1703633398` is the Unix timestamp when the link expires.

Which is:

- Tue Dec 26 2023 23:29:58 GMT+0000